# Вывести все буквы английского (Aa) и русского (Аа) алфавита (заглавные и строчные) в одном цикле

Tags: python

Английский алфавит заглавными и строчными буквами:

```
for i in range(65, 91):
  print(chr(i) + chr(i + 32) + ' ', end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

ну можно извратиться:

```
print(' '.join(sorted([chr(i) + chr(i).upper() for r in (range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1), range(ord('а'), ord('я') + 1), (ord('ё'),)) for i in r])))
```

а вот так можно чисто английский алфавит получить:

```
import string
print(' '.join(map(lambda l: l + l.upper(), string.ascii_lowercase)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lower_eng_char, upper_eng_char = [], []
lower_rus_char, upper_rus_char = [], []

for i in range(1040, 1072):
    if i - 975 <= 90:
        # Английские буквы
        upper_eng_char.append(chr(i - 975))
        lower_eng_char.append(chr(i - 943))

    # Русские буквы
    upper_rus_char.append(chr(i))
    lower_rus_char.append(chr(i + 32))
    # Ёё
    if i == 1045:
        upper_rus_char.append(chr(1025))
        lower_rus_char.append(chr(1105))

print(lower_eng_char)
print(upper_eng_char)

print(lower_rus_char)
print(upper_rus_char)
```

Comment: Ёж бы на вас обиделся бы ;-)

Comment: Не заметил, что __ё__ кодируется как число __1105__, что выходит за рамки цикла)